# Run JwtModule factory after APP_INITIALIZER has resolved

Tags: angular

Im trying to load the "allowedDomains" property for the `JwtModule` of [`@auth0/angular-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) from a configuration service.
I already have an `AppConfigurationService` which runs as `APP_INITIALIZER` that will generate the needed value.
For the `JwtModule`, I use a factory to generate the configuration. I want this factory to access the `AppConfigurationService` and get the appropriate value. The problem is that the JWT factory runs before `loadConfig` resolves.

AppConfigurationService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigurationService {

  public allowedHost: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  load(): Promise<any> {
    // loads JSON from a server and generates configuration out of that
    // returns a Promise since it uses Angulars HttpClient
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JWT_OPTIONS, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { AppConfigurationService } from './shared/configuration/app-configuration.service';
// ...


export function tokenGetter(): string {
  // returns the token for JWT
}

/**
 * Loads the app configuration via the AppConfigurationService
 */
export function loadConfig(configurationService: AppConfigurationService): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => configurationService.load();
}

/**
 * Factory for generating the configuration for the JwtModule.
 */
export function jwtConfigurationFactory(configurationService: AppConfigurationService): {} {
  return {
    tokenGetter,
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    authScheme: 'Bearer ',
    allowedDomains: [configurationService.allowedHost],
    skipWhenExpired: false,
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // ...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtConfigurationFactory,
        deps: [AppConfigurationService]
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppConfigurationService, {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadConfig,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppConfigurationService]
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Does anyone know how to make the `jwtConfigurationFactory` wait for `loadConfig` to resolve?

Comment: Can you put a console log in jwtConfigurationFactory fn and see if it gets invoked? Check this issue - https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/695

Comment: Already did that, it does, but it gets invoked before `loadConfig()` and therefore `configurationService.allowedHost` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
While I cannot change that the `jwtConfigurationFactory` runs before the `loadConfig` method, I can save a reference to the `allowedDomains` list.
This way I can update this list when `loadConfig` is called.
To prevent circular dependencies, I also had to extract these methods to their own files (otherwise `app.module.ts` would depend on `app-configuration.service.ts` and the other way around).

app.module.ts

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JWT_OPTIONS, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { AppConfigurationService } from './shared/configuration/app-configuration.service';
import { jwtOptions } from './jwt-utils';
// ...


/**
 * Loads the app configuration via the AppConfigurationService
 */
export function loadConfig(configurationService: AppConfigurationService): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => configurationService.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // ...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptions.options
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppConfigurationService, {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadConfig,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppConfigurationService]
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

jwt-utils.ts

```
/**
 * Returns the user's token. This function simply needs to make a retrieval
 * call to wherever the token is stored. In many cases, the token will be
 * stored in local storage or session storage.
 * @returns Returns the user's token.
 */
export function tokenGetter(): string {
  return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
}

/**
 * Factory for generating the configuration for the JwtModule.
 * @returns an object containing the desired options under the 'options' property
 * and a method to update the allowedDomains.
 */
export function jwtConfigurationFactory(): {
  options: () =>
    {
      tokenGetter: () => string;
      headerName: string;
      allowedDomains: any[];
      skipWhenExpired: boolean;
      authScheme: string
    };
  updateAllowedDomains: (newAllowedDomains: [string]) => void
} {
  const allowedDomains = [];

  /**
   * Clears the old entries and sets the allowed domains to the given value
   */
  function updateAllowedDomains(newAllowedDomains: [string]): void {
    while (allowedDomains.length > 0) {
      allowedDomains.pop();
    }

    allowedDomains.push(...newAllowedDomains);
  }

  return {
    updateAllowedDomains,
    options: () => ({
      tokenGetter,
      headerName: 'Authorization',
      authScheme: 'Bearer ',
      allowedDomains,
      skipWhenExpired: false
    })
  };
}

/**
 * Saves an instance of the object returned by jwtConfigurationFactory.
 * the options property can be passed to angular-jwt.
 * This object can be used to access the allowedDomains afterwards.
 */
export const jwtOptions = jwtConfigurationFactory();
```

In the `AppConfigurationService`, the allowed domains can now be updated via `jwtOptions.updateAllowedDomains(['myNewDomain']);`.

While this solution depends on the fact that the JwtModule does not save a copy but a reference to list, a contributor to this particular lib suggested that solution to another user: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/647#issuecomment-630186458